# How to run nodejs 0.10 on openshift?

Tags: node.js, openshift

I have created a Nodejs 0.10 cartridge on openshift but when i check the version with `node -v` I get v0.6.20. I think the old nodejs version is causing a conflict with the node-sass version I'm using. I've tried `echo -e "0.10.22\n" >> .openshift/markers/NODEJS_VERSION` but that hasn't done anything. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and was reported here https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1108951. That being said, if you deployed your application with nodejs-0.10 cartridge, your application will be launched using the node version 0.10. Check out the build function in https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-nodejs/bin/control for more information.